# Image files don't displayed in yii2

Tags: yii2

I need to help. I have some projects on yii2, but in each of them I can't to display images everything looks but it's still not working...

[image: for example]

[image: how it looks in browser]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also:

```
<img src="<?= \Yii::getAlias('@web/images/home.png') ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have wrong url for image  try

```
use yii\helpers\Url;

 <?php echo "<img src='". Url::base() . "/images/home.png' alt='your_alt' />" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<img src="<?=Yii::$app->request->baseUrl?>/images/home.png" />
```